# Change Opacity along a ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, color, opacity

I'm trying to change the opacity of a line in a ListLinePlot for increasing x-value.
E.g. the line should have opacity 1 at beginning and shade than down to opacity along the line.
I want to take the opacity value from another list whith the same amount of values as the list used for the ListLinePlot.
My current attempt is something like:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[results[[ind,1]], {ind, 1, 3599}], 
ColorFunction -> (Table[Opacity[results[[ind,2]], Red], {ind, 1, 3599}] &), 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

My results data has dimensions {3600,2}. All values of results[[ind,2]] are inbetween 0 and 1.

I would be greatful for every hint.
Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, 
Thank you already for your very useful comments!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the sample data generated by flinty, but affecting the the change in opacity using the `ColorFunction` option of `ListLinePlot`:

```
results = Table[{i, Sin[4 i]/2 + 1/2 + RandomReal[]*0.2}, {i, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.01}];
ListLinePlot[
 results,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Blend[{Red, White}, x/(2 Pi)]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 AspectRatio -> 1/5
 ]
```

[image: Output]

You can also use `Transparent` instead of `White`, but I didn't like the result of that as much.

Here's an example with a list of opacities rather than a continuous function:

```
xvalues = First /@ results;
opacities = #/(2 Pi) & /@ xvalues;
colors = MapThread[{#, RGBColor[1, 0, 0, #]} &, {xvalues, opacities}];
ListLinePlot[
 results,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Blend[colors, 1 - x/(2 Pi)]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 AspectRatio -> 1/5
 ]
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 7):

It's easier to do this sort of thing with `Graphics`:

```
results = Table[{i, Sin[4 i]/2 + 1/2 + RandomReal[]*0.2}, {i, 0, 2 π, 0.01}];
colours = RGBColor[1, 0, 0, #[[1]]/(2 π)] & /@ results;
Graphics[{Riffle[colours, Line /@ Partition[results, 2, 1]]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: fade out list plot graphics opacity]

Comment: Note I've used the first element #[[1]] which is the x-coordinate. ListLinePlot uses x-coordinates 1,2,3,4... implicitly so you may have to add these if you use Graphics. If you have trouble adapting this to your case, please provide a small amount of sample data and I can make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 6):

Using `results` and `colours` from flinty`s answer:

```
results = Table[{i, Sin[4 i]/2 + 1/2 + RandomReal[]*0.2}, {i, 0, 2 π, 0.01}];
colours = RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 1 - #[[1]]/(2 π)] & /@ results;
```

We can use `colours` as the option value for [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html):

```
Graphics[Line[results, VertexColors -> colours], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
colours2 = Opacity[1 - #, Red] & /@ Rescale[results[[All, 1]]];
Graphics[Line[results, VertexColors -> colours2], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it works now! Thanks a lot!
I have the impression that my example of a fading line confused more than it helped:
I wanted to weight my line with the opacity values from another list. Anyway you ideas where extremely helpful, and I just had to adjust the used function a litte. For people having the same question in the future :

```
yvalues = 
Table[results[[time, 1]], {time, 1,tend}]; (*y values as list*)

opacities = 
Table[results[[time, 2]], {time, 1, tend}]; (*corresponding opacities as list*)
colors = MapThread[{#1, RGBColor[1, 0, 0, #2]} &, {yvalues, opacities}];
ListLinePlot[yvalues, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colors[[x, 2]]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```